# Ubuntu 14.04 nautilus/nemo file manager hanging on every action

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager, debugging

I cannot use nautilus or nemo because of high loading time on each action, many times the applications simply hang and I've busted my time on trying to fix it with no success whatsoever.

Here's how i can describe it at this time:
Nautilus and Nemo both hang after opening, after a few minutes it loads the home directory, but when changing the folder to other it hangs again for a few minutes. (I've tried all the combo's possible, installed only nautilus, installed only nemo ...)

After failing with this i've tried mc commander from the terminal that works smooth.

My guess was that it was something wrong with x but i don't really know how to get some details about the problem from the system as I have not found something that seemed usefull to me when executing `gdb nautilus <proc_id>` or reading `dmesg` .

I would enjoy responding to your questions in order to solve this problem.

I also got throught this problem :

> The problem cannot be reported:
> You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs:
>
> initramfs-tools, initramfs-tools-bin, libgudev-1.0-0

Comment: Have you upgraded all your software to the latest available? In Terminal: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade